# Compile issue with mod_brotli and apache 2.4.33

Tags: apache, apache-modules, brotli

Getting the below issue with including mod_brotli support for Apache 2.4.33.

I compiled brotli which compiled fine but when i enable it in apache configure script using `--enable-brotli` and `--with-brotli=/apps/httpdx64/brotli`. I get the below error message when the apache is compiled:

```
/apps/httpdx64/apr/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/apps/httpdx64/brotli/include -g -O2 -pthread  -DSSL_EXPERIMENTAL_ENGINE   -L/apps/httpdx64/apache24/openssl/lib -L/usr/lib64 -L/apps/httpdx64/expat/lib      -o mod_brotli.la -rpath /apps/httpdx64/apache24/modules -module -avoid-version  mod_brotli.lo -L/apps/httpdx64/brotli/lib -lbrotlienc -lbrotlicommon -export-symbols-regex brotli_module
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbrotlienc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [mod_brotli.la] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/apps/httpdx64/httpd-2.4.33/modules/filters'
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/apps/httpdx64/httpd-2.4.33/modules/filters'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/apps/httpdx64/httpd-2.4.33/modules'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Please advise on how i can fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you have the brotli path set to your httpd folder (`--with-brotli=/apps/httpdx64/brotli`)?

I compile it like this (as [I explain here](https://www.tunetheweb.com/performance/brotli/)):

```
#You may need to install some dependencies if not already installed on your machine.
#For Centos/RHEL 7 the following should do this for you:
sudo yum install wget
sudo yum install perl
sudo yum install gcc
sudo yum install pcre-devel
sudo yum install cmake.x86_64   

cd ~
mkdir sources
cd sources

#Download and install brotli
git clone https://github.com/google/brotli.git
cd brotli/
git checkout v1.0
mkdir out && cd out
../configure-cmake
make
make test
sudo make install

#Download and install the latest Apache (needs to be 2.4.26 or above)
#For example:
wget http://mirrors.whoishostingthis.com/apache/httpd/httpd-2.4.33.tar.gz
wget https://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/httpd-2.4.33.tar.gz.asc
#Verify the package after download:
gpg --verify httpd-2.4.33.tar.gz.asc)
tar -zxvf httpd-2.4.33.tar.gz
cd httpd-2.4.33
./configure --with-pcre=/usr/bin/pcre-config --enable-ssl --enable-so --enable-brotli --with-brotli=/usr/local/brotli
make
sudo make install
```

Thanks,
Barry

Comment: I compile my own pcre, apr, apr-util, openssl from source code and include them into my apache build. I am following the same process for brotli. I do not want to depend on the binaries installed on the OS. I have seen dependency issues when the system libraries are upgraded that is reason i am compiling my own and including them with my apache binaries. Also brotli is not available as a standard package from the UNIX team. I compile the software required for Apache. This Apache rpm is consumed by the customers via yum.

Answer (score 0):

For people like me stumbling upon this identical issue, I resolved this by taking a shortcut and reinstalling Brotli *to* a location where the system looks for it.

Problem:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbrotlienc
```

Resolution:

1. Know where `ld` looks for `-lbrotlienc`. Do so by running:

   ```bash
   ld -lbrotlienc --verbose
   ```

   Near the end of the output, `ld` hints you where its trying to look for `-lbrotlienc`. In my case, the output looked something like:

   ```
   attempt to open //usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib64/libbrotlienc.so failed
   attempt to open //usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib64/libbrotlienc.a failed
   attempt to open //usr/lib64/libbrotlienc.so failed
   attempt to open //usr/lib64/libbrotlienc.a failed
   ...
   attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libbrotlienc.so failed
   ```
2. Pick a reasonable directory where to put the Brotli libraries. Based on the output above, I want to put the Brotli libraries under `/usr/local/lib64`.
3. Recompile and reinstall Brotli.

   1. `cd` to the directory where you ran `cmake` to build Brotli. In my case, that is:

      ```bash
      cd /usr/local/src/brotli-1.1.0/out/
      ```
   2. Remove previous Brotli installation and setup.

      ```bash
      xargs rm < install_manifest.txt
      cd /usr/local/src/brotli-1.1.0/
      rm -rf out/
      ```
   3. Prepare Brotli compilation, where you want its libraries to be placed.

      ```bash
      mkdir out && cd out
      cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=/usr/local ..
      ```
   4. Notice the value passed to the `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR` flag. This will tell where the Brotli library files will be placed. Now before recompiling, better check that `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR` took effect, by checking its value in `CMakeCache.txt`.

      ```bash
      cat CMakeCache.txt | grep CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR
      ```
   5. Finally, recompile Brotli.

      ```bash
      cmake --build . --config Release --target install
      ```
   6. Bonus: if you run `brotli --version` and get `symbol lookup error`, configure `ldconfig` as explained in [brotli/issues/1097](https://github.com/google/brotli/issues/1097#issuecomment-1945454509); just skip the compile part.

After these steps, Brotli linker errors should be gone when compiling httpd from source. Here's my compilation setup for httpd with Brotli enabled for your reference.

```bash
./configure --enable-brotli --with-brotli=/usr/local # irrelevant options snipped
```